# python script to monitor filesystem space using df -h

Tags: python

how to modify this script to alert me whenever block_usage_pct >90%

```
from __future__ import with_statement
import contextlib
import os
import sys 
print "Filesystem\tMounted on\tUse%\tIUse%"
with contextlib.closing(open('/etc/mtab')) as fp: 
  for m in fp: 
    fs_spec, fs_file, fs_vfstype, fs_mntops, fs_freq, fs_passno = m.split()
    if fs_spec.startswith('/'):
      r = os.statvfs(fs_file)
      block_usage_pct = 100.0 - (float(r.f_bavail) / float(r.f_blocks) * 100)
      inode_usage_pct = 100.0 - (float(r.f_favail) / float(r.f_files) * 100)
```

when i try this it says synatx invalid
          if (float(block_usage_pct)) >10
          print "%s\t%s\t\t%d%%\t%d%%" % (fs_spec, fs_file, block_usage_pct, inode_usage_pct)

Comment: Stack Overflow is no code writing service. Post your code and tell what the specific problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/89243/7524570) is a good reference on how to invoke `df -h` using Python, from there you can process the output and apply whatever rules you want to apply.

Comment: from __future__ import with_statement
import contextlib
import os
import sys 
print "Filesystem\tMounted on\tUse%\tIUse%"
with contextlib.closing(open('/etc/mtab')) as fp: 
  for m in fp: 
    fs_spec, fs_file, fs_vfstype, fs_mntops, fs_freq, fs_passno = m.split()
    if fs_spec.startswith('/'):
      r = os.statvfs(fs_file)
      block_usage_pct = 100.0 - (float(r.f_bavail) / float(r.f_blocks) * 100)
      print "%s\t%s\t\t%d%%\t%d%%" % (fs_spec, fs_file, block_usage_pct, inode_usage_pct)   i want to setup alert whenever block_usage_pct >90.